# Better way of handling repetitive code and exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

Given the following code:

```
_samedayServiceDescription = com_SubServiceDescriptionExtDS.COM_SubServiceDescriptionExt.Where(r => r.Description.Equals(samedayService)).First().ServiceSubServiceId;
_onedayServiceDescription = com_SubServiceDescriptionExtDS.COM_SubServiceDescriptionExt.Where(r => r.Description.Equals(onedayService)).First().ServiceSubServiceId;
_datedServiceDescription = com_SubServiceDescriptionExtDS.COM_SubServiceDescriptionExt.Where(r => r.Description.Equals(datedService)).First().ServiceSubServiceId;
_unpaidServiceDescription = com_SubServiceDescriptionExtDS.COM_SubServiceDescriptionExt.Where(r => r.Description.Equals(unpaidService)).First().ServiceSubServiceId;
_recallServiceDescription = com_SubServiceDescriptionExtDS.COM_SubServiceDescriptionExt.Where(r => r.Description.Equals(recallService)).First().ServiceSubServiceId;
```

I could get an exception on each `First()` call if the item I am expecting is not there, which could be the case if something in the configuration is missing. I would like to be able to tell at runtime which one throws an exception to give an informative message to say something like "hey, your configuration is missing the service for x".

The only way I can think of doing this is putting a `try`/`catch` block around each line. Surely there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: @Emad because `FirstOrDefault()` on a `DataRow` returns `null` which then turns into a `NullReferenceException` when I access it.

Comment: Is it possible to have a ServiceSubServiceId with a value of 0?

Comment: Unless I use C#6's nice little null propagation feature...

Comment: @Steve ServiceSubServiceId is a string.

Comment: Well then the question changes to: Is it possible to have a ServiceSubServiceID equals to a null string?

Comment: No, it's a PK in the database so no nulls allowed.

Comment: It's perfectly healthy to assume item doesn't exist in db. Your code should be able to handle that. My answer works I use this all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use C# 6 features, you can do it like that. First define generic extension method:

```
 public static class Extensions {
    public static T ThrowIfNull<T>(this T value, string msg) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

And then

```
_samedayServiceDescription = (com_SubServiceDescriptionExtDS.COM_SubServiceDescriptionExt
    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Description.Equals(samedayService))?.ServiceSubServiceId)
    .ThrowIfNull("hey, your configuration is missing the service for x");
```

Note that if your `ServiceSubServiceId` is struct (like `int`), the result of whole expression will be `int?`, while you might want it to be regular `int` still. In that case, you might use such extension method:

```
public static T ThrowIfNull<T>(this T? value, string msg) where T : struct {
    if (!value.HasValue) {
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    return value.Value;
}
```

You can use both extensions methods together, then for nullables the second one will be chosen, and for the rest - the first one.

Comment: Null will automatically throw. You just need to handle NullRefrenceException.

Comment: NullReferenceException will provide no information about which line exactly thrown it, so you will have to repeat try-catch 5 times if you want to provide meaningful exception.

Comment: Side note: FirstOrDefault can take the same lambda used for Where. This will remove a lot of clutter

Comment: Good point. But don't you think it's better to handle null instead of waiting for catch?

Comment: I like this. Then I'd be able to use `nameof` to figure what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use FirstOrDefault()

```
_samedayServiceDescription = com_SubServiceDescriptionExtDS.COM_SubServiceDescriptionExt.Where(r => r.Description.Equals(samedayService)).FirstOrDefault().ServiceSubServiceId;
_onedayServiceDescription = com_SubServiceDescriptionExtDS.COM_SubServiceDescriptionExt.Where(r => r.Description.Equals(onedayService)).FirstOrDefault().ServiceSubServiceId;
_datedServiceDescription = com_SubServiceDescriptionExtDS.COM_SubServiceDescriptionExt.Where(r => r.Description.Equals(datedService)).FirstOrDefault().ServiceSubServiceId;
_unpaidServiceDescription = com_SubServiceDescriptionExtDS.COM_SubServiceDescriptionExt.Where(r => r.Description.Equals(unpaidService)).FirstOrDefault().ServiceSubServiceId;
_recallServiceDescription = com_SubServiceDescriptionExtDS.COM_SubServiceDescriptionExt.Where(r => r.Description.Equals(recallService)).FirstOrDefault().ServiceSubServiceId;
```

Then handle nulls for each one. You can also use `??` at the end and initialize in place. Very clean. like this:

```
(com_SubServiceDescriptionExtDS.COM_SubServiceDescriptionExt.Where(r => r.Description.Equals(recallService)).FirstOrDefault()??new Type()).ServiceSubServiceId;
```

Comment: This code will raise NREs everytime FirstOrDefault returns null

Comment: Now this don't even compile, you can't return an int or an object reference on the same line

Comment: If it was me I would check for nulls before reading properties of them. It's the normal approach but I'm a fan of clean code and less local variables.

Comment: @Steve Did you replace "new Type()" with your type initializer?